# Computer runs slow in the startup screen and booting of windows, programs fade in and fade out slowly

Tags: windows-7, boot, performance, bios

I think I have the exact same problem that is described here: [PC running slow like molasses from BIOS to OS](https://superuser.com/questions/642731/pc-running-slow-like-molasses-from-bios-to-os). Everything was working fine, and then suddenly, out of nowhere it took forever to boot my pc. The BIOS screen hangs for about 1 minute before proceeding, and the windows bootup lasts several minutes (I have an SSD harddisk, usually it takes seconds). Opening and minimizing windows also goes really slowly, but the performance otherwise seems fine in windows. Games have really low FPS all of the sudden, around 3 or 7 FPS. I used to get 60 FPS. I can play Dark Souls 2 at around 40 FPS, but with plenty of weird graphical artifacts and super slow movements. I tried to upgrade my graphic card driver, but it didn't work.

It seems that accessing my BIOS could fix the problem, but I can't do this. First of all, my start up screen doesn't tell me how to access it, I can't remember if it did so before, but I've tried to frantically press every F key as well as esc and del during the bootup screen, but no dice. So therefore I was trying to flash my BIOS, but I can't for the life of me find the right driver, I've been searching the internet for any information at all on this for about 3 hours.

I have a 
AMI 4.6.4 Bios
with a 
Clevo P150HMx motherboard.

I can't identify the correct bios upgrade on the AMI webpage and Clevo, it seems, does not provide BIOS upgrades, even though it supposedly should.

If anyone could provide some insight into this problem, it would be greatly appreciated.

**Important edit:** As Wijagels pointed out, this might have to do with a failing USB-device, and as a matter of fact there is a very important piece of information that I forgot to mention. First of all, I'm on a laptop, so I can't easily disconnect the USB-ports physically or any other hardward, but the day before this problem started, I received constant messages of an USB-device not working properly (I don't know which), and the sound that windows makes when an USB-device is plugged in and out was playing constantly. Now I seem to be in a permanent state of an unknown device on Port_#0005.Hub_#0004 with error code 43, that doesn't go away, even if I unplug all USB-devices.

Does anybody have a suggestion in light of this?

Comment: Try booting with everything disconnected but the monitor.  You could just have a screwy usb device.

Comment: What kind of SSD hard drive? Samsung,Crucial, etc?  Have you updated the SSD firmware?

Comment: To Cybaernard: I Have a Samsung SSD 840 series. I did update my firmware, and while the bios still started up slowly and also windows for a second I thought that the problen with the programs fading in and out slowly within windows was fixed after the restart. But then I restarted again, and the exact same problem had returned. Strange.

Comment: Wijagels: I had actually forgotten about this, somehow! The day before this problem started, I had some problem with some USB-device, I could not figure out which. But Windows was going berserk with the sound of an USB-device getting unplugged and plugged, over and over again, even though I wasn't touching the computer.

Now I have an unnkown device on Port_#0005.Hub_#0004 with error code 43, and this does not go away, even if I unplug all the USB-devices. I am on a laptop, so I can't easily disconnect everything, do you have any suggestions?